# Get the original Request from OkHttp Response

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I have an OkHttp 3 Response, but I need the original Request that I made for this Response.

I am using Retrofit 2 as well, so I have Retrofit's Call and Response in a Callback:

```
@Override public void onResponse(Call<R> call, Response<R> response) {
  okhttp3.Response raw = response.raw();
}
```

How can I get the original okhttp3.Request that was created by my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [`Response.request()`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/0d867ab9fcc1fb197fedf40d9409e08d669caaba/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/Response.java#L84) is "the wire-level request that initiated this HTTP response." It is not necessarily the original Request.

The following will back up to the first Response and get its Request:

```
static Request originalRequest(okhttp3.Response response) {
  while (true) {
    okhttp3.Response prior = response.priorResponse();
    if (prior == null) {
      break;
    }
    response = prior;
  }
  return response.request();
}
```

However, note that the Request that you created at your application layer may have been recreated in an added Interceptor, and you will not necessarily know about that change. But, the above will work for most use cases.